# Checking if the user is logged in or not in Ember

Tags: ember.js

In my Ember App I am trying to check if the user is logged in or not. What I am trying to do is log in the user and when the user logs in successfully I get a session_token from the server which is then used to make other api calls. I want to check if the user is logged in and if the session_token is still validated when the user starts the application. Should I do it in my Router? Or should I do it in the index controller?

Answer (score 1):

Route has beforeModel hook, it fires before route makes actual request.

```
beforeModel: function(transition) {
 if (!this.checkForToken()) {
  this.redirectToLogin();
 }
}
```

Comment: Should it be written in ApplicationRoute?

Comment: You should do it only in protected routes. In my app i created authRoute with beforeModel method, and all other protected routes extend from it. f.e. indexRoute = authRoute.extend({})